# UIButton in UITableViewCell not releasing the UIViewController it creates

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

In my `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `UIButton` inside that should push a newly made `UIViewController`.

I made two methods like this :

```
- (void)configureCellWithObject:(Object *)object {
    self.object = object;
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(initCustomController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // self.button1 is a UIButton
}

- (void)initCustomController {
    CustomViewController *cvc = [[CustomViewController alloc]initWithObject:self.object];
        // self.nc is the navigation controller of the UITableView presenting the cell
        [self.nc pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
}
```

And my issue is that the `CustomViewController` created is never released when I touch the "`back`" button in the upper left corner (it disappear but isn't released).

If I do all that in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` it works as I expected and get properly released.

I though I did everything right but can't figure out how to make it right :(

EDIT : YES I am using `ARC`

Comment: Yes forgot to mention it thanks

Comment: the burden of releasing the customviewcontroller is left to the compiler. so it takes care of when to release the customviewcontroller.

Comment: I'm sure I made a mistake because it never get released `ever`

Comment: how do u know it is never released? are u saying that the back button in the viewcontroller is not returning u to the tableview?

Comment: Yes it returns to the tableView but in Instruments I still see the CustomViewController living ! and the number increase each time I click the button and never decrease

Comment: check my answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000356/ios-7-how-to-get-the-indexpath-from-button-placed-in-uitableviewcell/19000484#19000484 you do not need a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom button and in tableviewCellForRowAtIndexPath give each button different tag like to pass selected value if needed otherwise not.

```
cell.button.tag= indexPath.row + 1;
```

You can write your button method like that

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And in the method btnClicked just write your code for navigation.

Just hope that it'll work for you

Comment: Thanks but I know that and I don't really like tags, the goal was `if possible` to make it work in the method from the cell

Comment: you can add target to button like in the given answer. And in that method just write your navigation code. If you don't want to assign tag then it's ok because you want to simply navigate. Right ?

Comment: Don't worry I understood what you meant I just don't want to use `tags` :p Yeah just navigate but each row create a different controller. If I don't find any answer I'll mark yours as valid but I'm still waiting for another answer ;)