# IOS 7 - How to get the indexPath from button placed in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios7

I've programmatically created a UITableView and added UISwitch to it's cell accessory view.

This is my code for UISwitch in cell accessory view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
UISwitch *accessorySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[accessorySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
[accessorySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
cell.accessoryView = accessorySwitch;
```

This is the method which is called after the button is clicked.

```
- (void)changeSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.filterTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath);

 ……………. My other code…….
}
```

I am able to print the index path value in iOS 6
But in iOS 7 it prints nil,

Am i missing anything in iOS 7 or there is some other approach to get the indexPath in iOS 7

Thanks,
Arun.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath);` is wrong this will print the pointer address of indexPath

try using following codes

```
CGPoint center= sender.center; 
  CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.filterTableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.filterTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
  NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
```

Comment: it's too printing null

Comment: can you also print sender.center?  and rootViewPoint

Comment: And if you were curious, the same thing for UICollectionView:
CGPoint center = button.center;
CGPoint rootViewPoint = [button.superview convertPoint:center toView:collection];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collection indexPathForItemAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
NSDictionary *type = [self.serviceTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 8):

**Swift** solution:
A UITableView extension like this one can be useful for this.

```
extension UITableView {
    func indexPathForView(view: AnyObject) -> NSIndexPath? {
        let originInTableView = self.convertPoint(CGPointZero, fromView: (view as! UIView))
        return self.indexPathForRowAtPoint(originInTableView)
    }
}
```

Usage becomes easy everywhere.

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForView(button)
```

Comment: Very good. It worked. Thanks. CGPointZero doesn't exist in Swift. Use         let originInTableView = self.convert(CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), from: (view as! UIView))

Answer (score 6):

If you have button in cell. You can get cell by calling superview. And then can get Indexpath by this way.

```
 (void)obButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Comment: This is not iOS 7 dependent man... check your code might be issue with your code.

Comment: iOS 7 changed the hierarchy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162725/access-ios-7-hidden-uitableviewcellscrollview

Comment: you should write as .. `UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview` then

Answer (score 4):

You can assign tags to each switch in cellForRowAtIndexPath method like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
   UISwitch *accessorySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   [accessorySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
   [accessorySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   cell.accessoryView = accessorySwitch; 
   accessorySwitch.tag = indexPath.row;    
}

- (void)changeSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[sender tag]];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath);
}
```

Comment: But i need both indexPath.row and indexPath.section in my code.

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 4 :

```
extension UITableView {
    func indexPathForView(view: AnyObject) -> NSIndexPath? {
        let originInTableView = self.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: (view as! UIView))
        return self.indexPathForRow(at: originInTableView)! as NSIndexPath
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to go through the effort of grabbing someone else's answer and converting it to Swift 4, I would at least fix bad practices like force-unwrapping that AnyObject to a UIView. Or, since it's Swift 4, changing NSIndexPath to IndexPath

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 4 Conversion, creates global extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func indexPathForView(view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
            let originInTableView = self.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: (view))
            return self.indexPathForRow(at: originInTableView)
        }
}
```

Usage example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = ...
cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myButtonAction(_:)), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
return cell

    }

@objc func myButtonAction(_ button:UIButton) {

        guard let ip = self.tableView.indexPathForView(view: button) else {
            return
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting burned, making the assumption that the switch's `superview` is going to be the `tableViewCell`. Maybe in iOS 7 they changed the hierarchy to achieve some sort of visual effect; maybe there is a new view inserted in there.

You could possibly subclass `UISwitch` and give it an `indexPath` property. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, assign it there so you have a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on **Swift5.x**

if you want to get row number when you click on the button placed in tableViewCell, Then the below function will work.

```
 @IBAction func buttonClickeAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let btnPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
      let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: btnPoint)
      print(indexPath?.row)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is dangerous to rely on the position of the button to know which one have been clicked.

I prefere create a dictionary taking as a key the button/switch itself, and as a value the indexpath :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSValue * accessorySwitchKey = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:[cell settingSwitch]];
    [[self switchIndexDictionary]setObject:indexPath accessorySwitchKey];
...
}
```

then when the switch/button is triggered I get the indexpath easily from my dictionary  :

```
- (void)toggleSetting:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *selectedSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender;

    NSValue * accessorySwitchKey = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:selectedSwitch];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self switchIndexDictionary]objectForKey: accessorySwitchKey];
}
```