# Access iOS 7 hidden UITableViewCellScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Apple change the `UITableViewCell` hierarchy in iOS 7

Using iOS 6.1 SDK

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    | <UILabel>
```

Using iOS 7 SDK

```
<UITableViewCell>
   | <UITableViewCellScrollView>
   |    | <UITableViewCellContentView>
   |    |    | <UILabel>
```

My problem is that the `UITableViewCellScrollView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE` by default and i need it to be false.

I tried the following:

```
UIView * scrollView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

and

```
[self.myLabel.superview.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
```

But non of them changes the `UITableViewCellScrollView`.
How can i access this scrollview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to access the new CellScrollView is by accessing the cell superview after it was created.

I added the following `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell = [[UICustomTableViewCell alloc] init];
UIView *cellScrollView = cell.myLabel.superview;
[cellScrollView.layer setMasksToBounds: NO];
```

I think Apple should give us a way to access this new ScrollView without hacking.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C:

```
UIView *cellScrollView = [[cell contentView] superview];
[cellScrollView setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

Swift:

```
let cellScrollView = cell.contentView.superview
cellScrollView?.clipsToBounds = false
```