# button inside cellView I can't know which cell user pressed

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have custom cell in tableView
inside it I have a button , I want when user click on the button push viewController, how I can do that and how I can know which cell user use its button, because here not `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000356/ios-7-how-to-get-the-indexpath-from-button-placed-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: @JJBoursier I want that in swift, could you explain that for me ? I have no idea about objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Add Tag of button in Cell and add Target for your transition Function

```
func    tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as!   CustomCell
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(    self.transitonMethod    ), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
return cell

}
```

## Fetch indexPath from tag of sender Button and Fetch Cell for this indexPath.Push your controller on your navigation controller

```
func transitonMethod(sender: AnyObject){
 let indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(index: sender.tag)
 let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourController, animated: true)
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom button class

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
     var indexPath: NSIndexPath!
}
```

In your custom cell create the button of the CustomButton type add the following lines in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.yourCustomButton.indexPath = indexPath
```

Define `IBAction` like this

```
@IBAction func customButtonClicked(sender: CustomButton) {
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = sender.indexPath
    // Do whatever you want with the indexPath
}
```

Comment: To access `sender.indexPath` sender should be of type CustomButton.

Comment: Edited. Thanks @SamM

Answer (score 0):

Declare an IBAction as follow as suggested in [IOS 7 - How to get the indexPath from button placed in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000356/ios-7-how-to-get-the-indexpath-from-button-placed-in-uitableviewcell) :

```
@IBAction func didTapOnButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = sender.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    // Do anything with the indexPath
}
```

Or the other method :

```
@IBAction func didTapOnButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let center: CGPoint = sender.center
    let rootViewPoint: CGPoint = sender.superview?.convertPoint(center, toView: tableView)
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(rootViewPoint!)
    print(indexPath)
}
```

Then work with that indexPath to do whatever you need.

Comment: I wrote in this UItableViewCell class  but I got error, it say "has no member "tableView"

Comment: You must declare this method in the ViewController that contains the TableView...
1 - Drop a UIButton in your cell, add constraints ;
2 - Declare the IBAction method in the ViewController containing the TableView ;
3 - Link the button to the cell and you whatever graphical (like set the title) inside the cell's controller ;
4 - Link the sent event to the ViewController where you declared the IBAction through the storyboard ;

Comment: @JJBoursier Your first method is not safe as it relies on the architecture of the tableViewCell, and it is also wrong because `sender.superview` will not get you the cell, it will get you to the `tableViewCellContentView`. To get to the cell you need to go two layers up, like `(sender.superview)?.superview`

Comment: Ijust translated the related post into Swift.

Answer (score 0):

In cellforRow method of tableview:

1) set tag of your button e.g. yourButton.tag = indexpath.row

2) set target method of yourbutton e.g.buttonPressed(sender:UIButton)

3) Now in that target method you will get indexpath.row by sender.tag